# Pokemon gyms and pokestop disappears

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm wondering why every time I use my mobile data to hunt Pokémon, Pokéstops, gyms and nearby list just starting to disappear. When in WIFI mode it works very well. Gyms and Pokéstop that has been loaded in WIFI mode are the only place I can go with mobile data. But as I go far to discover new spots, everything just vanishes. My character moves as I walk around but there's none of anything!

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone you can try (it worked for me):

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings